# Xubuntu 14.10 reboot problem

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 14.10

I'm running a HP 255 laptop. I was happily running Xubuntu 14.04 on it and this morning accepted the upgrade to 14.10.

All went well. I rebooted and have been using 14.10 all day.

However, I rebooted again this evening and now it won't boot up.

It gets as far as the Xubuntu 14.10 splash screen with the moving dots below it and sits there forever.

I have booted into safe mode and run both `fsck` and `dpkg`. Package manager says I'm up to date (as I should be) and `fsck` found a load of errors in the `/tmp` directory, which I fixed.

In safe mode `fsck` now runs clean but the system won't boot. I'm typing this on an old Toshiba I pulled out of the cupboard as it's the only machine I have available that works.

Any hints or tips to try would be most gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com. Please include output of `dmesg` into your post. Perhaps others can spot possible boot errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Wait until the BIOS has finished loading.

Press and hold the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with recovery mode, something like:

```
Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-23-generic (recovery mode)
```

Press enter to boot.

In a sub menu with a number of options.

Select:

```
Network.
and
Drop to root shell prompt.
```

In a terminal

Run it

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments so far. I haven't been able to get hold of dmesg output yet. What I did do was take quiet and spalsh out of the start up and the boot stalled at the following line:

* Stopping cold plug devices                 [OK]
* Stopping log initial device creation       [OK]

I had a quick google and found a problem with lightdm starting. I booted in recovery mode, dropped to root and typed in:

service lightdm restart and it started the xubuntu desktop manager and I was able to work. I then, foolishly, accepted an update and now it doesn't work. Job failed to start.

Comment: Asever, any comments gratefully received

Comment: I've done some more playing around. I read some threads that suggested that using GDM might help (it didn't.) However, during that process I removed and purged lightdm from the system. I've now put lightdm back (and selected it as default) and I can now get a desktop by booting into recovery mode, dropping to root and typing service lightdm restart.

Comment: @Richard Owen I am facing the same problem. When i restart the lightdm service i get a blank screen. Did you also get a blank screen?